# Space skeletons on the moon killed by an air cannon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was read 40 years ago, in America, from an elementary school library.

It is a children's story about astronauts discovering hostile living skeletons on the moon, possibly pirates. The astronauts kill the skeletons with air.

Comment: When did you read this?

Comment: Hello.  This question is really, really … sparse.  It doesn't look good, either.  :-(  It looks like the sort of thing you'd ask in a chatroom; here, questions and answers should have a certain level of refinement and format.  Oh, and anyway, there's a list somewhere which tells you what information to include when you ask [tag:story-identification] here.  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info

Comment: The only other specific I can remember from 40 years ago was that the book was in the library of Spalding Elementary School in Suffield, CT USA. After good luck with a previous question perhaps I got carried away

Comment: This is probably the same book as asked about here:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116155/childrens-science-fiction-book-from-the-70s-oxygen-guns-used-to-defeat-aliens

Comment: It could be _Bone People_ by Henry A. Bamman

Answer (score 5):

There is little to go on here, but everything you have described sounds like *Mighty Mouse and the Moon Men*.  The titular hero travels to the moon to investigate some kind of menace.  He encounters a race of thin, almost skeletal aliens (rather creepy looking in the cartoon illustration).  I think they are actually from the asteroid belt, just using the moon for a base.  Eventually, Mighty Mouse defeats them with a gun that shoots air, which seems to "freeze" the vacuum-dwelling creatures.

Here is an illustration from the book (colorized and texturized by somebody else—the original was black and white) showing Mighty Mouse's first sighting of the moon men.

[image: Mighty Mouse and the Moon Men]

Comment: Bizarre.  I don't think I ever saw that one.  Did the description in the question simply trigger a recollection, or did you need to stew on that one for a while?

Comment: Sparse is right. Read this one in 1977 and it seemed at least ten years old then. According to Amazon Mighty Mouse book was published 1980, and I don't remember any mice. Skeletons were frightening.