# Children's sci-fi book with astronauts fighting skeletons on the moon

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I am searching for a book that I first read back in elementary school, in the 1970s. The book was illustrated, and around 100 pages.

It concerned astronauts in a war with these aliens that were skeletons, or bone men if I remember correctly.  The bone men had uniforms, but didn't need air to live on the moon, and the astronauts were able to fight them using magnetism, and could fire at them with ball bearings or hammers.

I'm sure it was a part of a series of books that were science fiction for kids, and as I read these back in the 70's, maybe published in the 50's or 60's.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: I think I may have read this one too -- found it in an elementary school library, which was also where I became familiar with Tom Swift, Nancy Drew, the Hardy Boys, the Bobbsey Twins . . . I have no idea who wrote it, but I'll be watching to see if someone else comes up with an answer!

Comment: Probably the same book as this question asks about:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116155/childrens-science-fiction-book-from-the-70s-oxygen-guns-used-to-defeat-aliens

Comment: Perhaps Mighty Mouse and the Moon Men: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160976/space-skeletons-on-the-moon-killed-by-an-air-cannon/161028

Answer (score 6):

*Bone People* by Henry A. Bamman

[image: book cover]

It's book three in the [Space science fiction series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/105885-space-science-fiction).

The [National Library of Australia](https://trove.nla.gov.au/work/21265741?q&versionId=25398102) entry for the book says it is 72 pages and illustrated.

Comment: Thank you; I do believe that's it. I think I checked this one (and some other science fiction by the same author) out from a school library when I was in either first or second grade. Ah, the memories . . .